# UIbutton deallocated in custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton

Using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), I have a UIButton in a subclassed `UITableViewCell`.  The table view controller implements the `IBAction` which is hooked up to the `UIButton`.  In the subclassed cell's xib, the same table view controller is the File's Owner.

The problem occurs when I run the app and click on the button, I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.  It's clearly visible on the iPhone screen, so it is being allocated at some point.

Any idea what the problem could be?  Thanks in advance!

EDIT1:
Note:  I have env variable `NSZombieEnabled` set to true.
Here's the console:

```
2011-10-31 22:22:08.653 MyApp[7176:fb03] *** -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6b94d40
(lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x014c3e1e CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 206, stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
frame #0: 0x014c3e1e CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 206
frame #1: 0x014c3ce2 CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
frame #2: 0x001e45c2 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
frame #3: 0x001e455a UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
frame #4: 0x00289b76 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
frame #5: 0x0028a03f UIKit`-[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 503
frame #6: 0x002892fe UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 549
frame #7: 0x004a2a2a UIKit`_UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 6725
frame #8: 0x015319ce CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
frame #9: 0x014c8670 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoObservers + 384
frame #10: 0x014944f6 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1174
frame #11: 0x01493db4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
frame #12: 0x01493ccb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #13: 0x02449879 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 207
frame #14: 0x0244993e GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 114
frame #15: 0x001e1a9b UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1175
frame #16: 0x0000278d MyApp`main + 125 at main.m:14
frame #17: 0x00001ff5 MyApp`start + 53
```

Comment: Why do you think it's been deallocated?  That's not the only reason to get EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  Show us the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  I was using `UINib`'s `instantiateWithOwner: options:` to load the nib of the custom `UITableViewCell`.  I was setting the owner to `nil`.  Setting the owner to my view controller fixed it.  Also, my view controller is the `File's Owner` of that `UITableViewCell` nib.  I'm guessing because the view controller and nib were not properly linked, ARC did not see a reason to keep the view around.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I have a feeling your problem is in the selector you are passing to the button.

Try to see if you are using a selector with ":" to a method with out parameters.

If you are using selector that looks like this:

```
@selector(method:)
```

Then is is expected that "method" will take parameters:

```
-(IBAction)method:(UIButton)sender{
}
```

if your function is not taking any parameters:

```
-(IBAction)method{
}
```

then your selector should look like that:

```
@selector(method)
```